# Syntax Error (missing operator) in query expresssion in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, syntax-error

Access gives me a runtime error 3075 Syntax Error (missing operator). The SQL works in MS SQL Server 2012 but it doesn't work in Acces. Can someone help me?

Code:

```
CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Gebruiker.[emailadres] FROM Voorwerp INNER
JOIN Bod ON Voorwerp.[Voorwerpnummer] = Bod.[Voorwerpnummer] INNER JOIN
[Gebruiker] ON Gebruiker.[GebruikersID] = Bod.[GebruikersID] WHERE Voorwerp.
[Voorwerpnummer] = 1")
```

Thank you in advance!

Carsten Flokstra

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MS Access requires more parentheses for joins.  Try this:

```
SELECT Gebruiker.[emailadres]
FROM (Voorwerp INNER JOIN
      Bod
      ON Voorwerp.[Voorwerpnummer] = Bod.[Voorwerpnummer]
     ) INNER JOIN
     [Gebruiker]
     ON Gebruiker.[GebruikersID] = Bod.[GebruikersID]
WHERE Voorwerp.[Voorwerpnummer] = 1;
```